# Not able to create a new folder inside my drives in ubuntu

Tags: 20.04

I am not able to create a new folder on my all drives in Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

Screenshot of the drives.
[image]

[image]
[image]
In all the drives I am not able to create a new folder but I am able to create a new folder in downloads, desktop.
Please help me with this issue.

Comment: It may be the case that the drives are mounted read-only or you may not have  write permission.

Comment: It's my laptop How I get that permission? I am new to ubuntu. Please help me

Comment: Have you tried: `sudo usermod -aG disk [username]` ? Logoff and back in for the change to take effect.

Comment: I didn't try that.what does it do?

Comment: I tried that but didn't work for me

Answer (score 2):

Looking at `RECYCLE BIN` and `SVI` I guess you have dual booted with windows

If you have `windows 10` then it has a feature of `fast-startup` which makes drives `read only.`

How to turn it off??
[See this](https://help.uaudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/213195423-How-To-Disable-Fast-Startup-in-Windows-10?mobile_site=true#:%7E:text=To%20disable%20Fast%20Startup%2C%20press,the%20column%20on%20the%20left.)

If have already done this but still get this, that means your windows was not `properly shutdown` (eg. Some of your application was open when you turn your laptop off)

To overcome this just boot to windows and then shutdown it properly

Hope this helps :))

Comment: Hell there, I didn't dual boot the system. I am using only ubuntu 20.04 desktop

Comment: Then why is there those bin files. Okay leave it 1. Copy all of your data out of those a drives then just format those drives then its all yours